# HUGO: problem with the structure of the app - index.md issue

Tags: markdown, structure, hugo

Here is the structure of my hugo app in the directory `content`:

```
content
├── _index.md
└── folder
    ├── index.md
    ├── folder1
            └── index.md
    ├── folder2
            └── index.md
    ├── folder3
            └── index.md
```

When I am running my app, when I go to `localhost:1313/folder`, I can see the index.md, but then when I go to `folder/folder1` or `folder/folder2` or `folder/folder3`, it gives me a 404 error page not found.

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I'm a bit confused.

Also, I tried to rename the file `folder/index.md` as `folder/_index.md`, like that:

```
content
├── _index.md
└── folder
    ├── _index.md <---- here is the change
    ├── folder1
            └── index.md
    ├── folder2
            └── index.md
    ├── folder3
            └── index.md
```

When I am doing that, the content inside `folder/folder1` or `folder/folder2` or `folder/folder3` is working and displaying but the content of `folder/_index.md` is not displaying anymore BUT I don't get any 404 error.

I don't know why but it seems this file gets ignore cause of the `_` ahead.

I don't know what I forgot or what I missed, if someone could help me !

Comment: What theme are you using? Do you override any of the theme layout files with your own layout files? If so, post those layout files (in addition to posting a link to your theme).

Answer (score 1):

While Hugo supports nested folders .. the top level folders like `content/blog` are special for content types and identifying the layout associated to that content type.

Each folder should also have a file `_index.md` note the _ in the filename is important - these files also help with organisation for content types and taxonomies

see also [Hugo Docs](https://gohugo.io/content-management/organization/)